# Angular CLI: Mount app to domain subpath - relative paths for static files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My Angular2 application, built with ng build --prod, is mounted to https://[domainname]/app.
The problem is that scripts and styles injected in index.html have paths like

```
src="styles.8e0edbbd6ad2cb36be49.bundle.js"
```

so page is trying to look for them in root.
How to change it to:

```
src="./styles.8e0edbbd6ad2cb36be49.bundle.js"
```

Or is there other correct way to deploy app to domain subpath with Angular CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below  command for building angular 2 using cli

```
# Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html
ng build --base-href /myUrl/
ng build --bh /myUrl/
```